# implement procedural for loop in haskell, tracking multiple variables

Tags: haskell

I am trying to do some alpha-beta pruning, [here's an example of an algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning) I can understand and the algorithm I *think*  of when I think how I would approach this problem.

But I have to write this in Haskell and am struggling to "convert" my way of thinking from procedural for-loops and variable etc. to Haskell's functional approach.

The part that's got me stumped p much is how to write something like

```
function alphabeta(node, α, β, player) is
    .
    .
    value := −∞
    for each child of node do
        value := max(value, alphabeta(child, α, β, otherPlayer))
        α := max(α, value)
        if α ≥ β then
            break (* β cut-off *)
    return value
    .
    .
```

I realise I can *kind of* do for-loops with a fold, e.g.

```
foldl (max ... alphabeta ...) -∞ (children node)
```

But I see that I need to break from the loop when `α ≥ β`.

I wondered if I could switch to using `scanl` and `dropWhile`, maybe something like

```
head $ dropWhile (<b) $ scanl (max ... alphabeta ...) -∞ (children node)
```

but no! looks like I am meant to compare the *changing* variable `α` with β.

The for loop is constantly changing and using (in its recursion) two different variables, `α` and `value`, and that's what's throwing me off, I have no idea how to "track" two different variables that influence each other (so like, figuring out a recursive solution as I may attempt for single-variable loops becomes difficult, at least to me).

I'm just wondering what I can do to better understand how to approach this problem.

Comment: Your pseudocode has the right idea.  Think of for loop as a function, and at the end of that function where you do the >= test, decide whether the function should return the result of calling itself recursively (with different parameters) or simply return the result it has so far.  I don't think I understand your logic well enough to write a working example with confidence, but your function would likely be calling itself recursively on a smaller list of children with possibly updated values of value and alpha.

Comment: I see a tree at the Wikipedia page. Haskell is very good with trees (as it can be defined as a recursive data-structure). I would try to exploit that fact. Can't you do it using a recursive function for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most fundamental form of "looping" is recursion. In fact, `fold` is implemented via recursion under the hood, and while `fold` makes it more manageable and harder to get wrong, you can always drop down to the most basic level if you don't see how to use a fold.

The rule of thumb is this: every time you would "go to next iteration", call the function recursively, and all the state that changes from one iteration to another becomes the function arguments. When you want to "break" from the loop - simply don't call the function recursively.

With that said, your algorithm would look something like this:

```
alphabeta node initialAlpha beta player =
    ...
    let value = loop minBound initialAlpha (childrenOf node)
    in
    ...
    where
    loop value alpha [] = value 
    loop value alpha (child:restOfChildren) =
        let newValue = max value (alphabeta child alpha beta otherPlayer)
            newAlpha = max alpha value
        in
            if newAlpha >= beta 
                then newValue 
                else loop newValue newAlpha restOfChildren
```

At the entry point, I call `loop` passing it `minBound` as `value` and all children of `node` as a list.

The loop itself then matches on the list of children it's been passed: if the list is empty, the result of the loop is `value`; if the list of children is not empty, `loop` performs the calculation on the first child and then calls itself recursively, passing to the next iteration new values of `value` and `alpha`, and the rest of the children; unless `newAlpha >= beta`, in which case the result of `loop` is the current (just-calculated) `value`.

Comment: What's the recursive part meant to look like? To calculate newValue

Comment: I don't think I quite understand the question.

Comment: `(alphabeta child alpha beta otherPlayer)` all of these terms are undefined and it's the part I find most difficult.

Comment: `child` and `alpha` are defined, and the rest come from your own example, so I assumed you do have them defined somehow.

Comment: alphabeta is the recursive function I am trying to build, the for loop is a little component inside of the definition of alphabeta. I just edited to make that clearer

Comment: Oooooh! Got it. Will amend the answer shortly.

Comment: Sorry it was kind of unclear, I'm frazzled at the moment and wrote the question lazily. In the end that made more work for you, thank you for all your help so far man—and yeah sorry about that :c

Comment: Ok, amended the answer

Comment: Thanks. I managed to figure this out in the last hour lmao, my EUREKA! moment was just like 2 minutes before you updated the answer I was about to write my own x) Thanks for helping me out sm Fyodor